# Calendar event QR using Google tools?

Tags: google-api, qr-code

Is it possible to generate callendar event type QR code using Google chart tools: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes.html

Comment: Just found how to do it. You need to pass specific structure of data into QRs source.

Example:

    BEGIN:VEVENT
    SUMMARY:Concert
    DTSTART:20110912
    DTEND:20110912
    DESCRIPTION:Metallica concert
    END:VEVENT

Will generate vCal type QR like this: http://goo.gl/0xOZN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just choose "Calendar" here: http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/

It is actually just creating a link to the Google Chart Server to make the QR code. So you can copy the link out of the page, just below the image.

Comment: Need was to create these QRs automaticaly (web application generates QR for every item) not by manual clicking.
So all I needed was structure and syntax which must be passed to create Calendar event.
As I said in my comment, I've already done this.

Anyway, thank you Sean, your answer is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you would like that when you scan the QR code it redirects to "new event" page and uses event type specified by you ?

Comment: For example: http://goo.gl/0xOZN
When u scan it with cell phone, it will be saved as calendar event.

Comment: Ok, so what would you exactly want to do ?

Comment: I want to generate this type (vCal) QR code using Google chart tools.
Maybe there is some kind of formating (eg. xml tags) which I have to include in QRs source?