# QR code result handling

Tags: qr-code

I want to be able to scan a QR code that would write something like "30,69 Fake Street, $10"
And return something like:

```
Time: 30

Location: 69 Fake street

Cost: $10
```

Is this possible, Would i need to modify my code too much to handle this, Do i need to use different call signs for each different piece of information.

Comment: What do you mean by "write" and "return"?

Comment: By write i mean that i would want if possible the QR code to read that format of information, And by return i mean i would like to be able to display it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `%0A` character to generate a newline, `%3A` for the colon, `%24` for the dollar sign, and `%20` for the space character.

Eg

`Time%3A%2030%%0ALocation%3A%2069%20Fake%20street%0ACost%3A%20%2410`

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to automatically set a event (say -10 mins of the time) in the code or would i need to extract this from the extract it from the code and write up some code to set a reminder?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377506/calendar-event-qr-using-google-tools

Comment: That shows that it isnt possible to either have it set to a time after scan type reminder, or to have both a reminder and information like i want in the same display like i want (As seen above)

Comment: No - there is no way to say "30 minutes from the time you scanned" - unless you either build you own scanner, or regenerate the QR code on a computer screen once per minute.

Comment: Is there no feature on android that allows you to set a timer to go off x mins after scan

Comment: No. You'd have to write your own.